# JQuery Table Traversal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, traversal

I have a table as follows:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input id="c1" type="text" class=""></td>
    <td><input id="c2" type="text" class="readonly"></td>
    <td><input id="c3" type="text" class=""></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I'm implmenting some custom cell keyboard navigation, and for example, I would like to be able to move focus to a new cell on keyboard input, but skip over cells that match a given selector (Pressing the right arrow at the end of `#c1` should move focus to the next cell that is not `.readonly`, likewise, pressing the left arrow at the beginning of `#c3` should move focus to the last cell that is not `.readonly`.

I've got the code working to handle the keyboard events, but I'm having issues with my jQuery selector to move focus around. I can easily do what I want in a loop, but am looking for a more elegant way to do this. The selector I'm current using (for example, move "previous" from `#c3` to `#c2`, (intended to be `#c1`)) is:

```
$(el).parent('td').prev('td').find('input').focus();
```

How can I basically do:

`Element -> Parent 'td' -> Closest previous 'td' containing an 'input' element without the 'readonly' class`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$(el).closest('td').prevAll('td:has(input:not(.readonly))').first().find('input').focus();
```

Comment: `'td:has(input:not(.readonly))'` the input is readonly, not the td